# How do I iterate through all the objects in a container?

Tags: arrays, vb.net, object, collections

If I have a panel with an unknown number of labels in it, how do I go through all of the labels and change the .text value in them? I tried something like this:

```
for each x as label in mypanel
   x.text = "whatever"
next
```

but I get an error that mypanel is not a collection.

The labels are children of mypanel.

Comment: [`mypanel.Controls`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.controls.aspx) - this brought to you by the Committee of Reading The Documentation For You.

Comment: Thanks for the info. While I appreciate the sarcasm, the link really doesn't help answer the question. I know the object has controls, but the question is how do I iterate through them.

Comment: That's the actual property that will let you iterate over them. In fact your accepted answer uses it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for win forms try:

```
for each x as Control in mypanel.Controls
   if TypeOf x Is Label Then
     CType(x, Label).text = "whatever"
   end if
next
```

Comment: Thanks, but I don't want to have to ask what type of control it is because I may not know and I don't want to have to ask for every type of control. I may have more than just labels.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what kind of `Panel` this is.  [WinForms](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.panel.aspx)?  [WPF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.panel.aspx)?  The error is right, `Panel` isn't a collection.  It's just an object.  But one of its properties is probably a collection.

`mypanel.Controls` for WinForms, or `mypanel.Children` for WPF.  If there is more hierarchy than direct children then you may need to recurse further into that hierarchy.

Answer (score 0):

```
For Each lbl As Label in myPanel.Controls
     lbl.Text = "whatever"
Next
```

This is assumes all that is on myPanel are labels.  If there are other controls you will have to test that they are a label:

```
For Each ctl as Control in myPanel.Controls
     If Ctl.GetType = Label.GetType Then
        CType(ctl, Label).text = "whatever"
     End if
Next
```

Comment: Depending on your VB version, you can also do `For Each ctl in myPanel.Controls(Of Label)` and get only the label controls.

Answer (score 0):

Loop through all the controls in the panel and then determine if each control is a `Label`, like this:

```
For Each theControl As Control In myPanel.Controls
    If TypeOf theControl Is Label Then
        ' Change the text here
        TryCast(theControl, Label).Text = "whatever"
    End If
Next
```

UPDATE:

To account for child controls in your panel, then do this:

```
Dim listOfLabels As New List(Of Control)

Public Sub GetAllLabelsIn(container As Control)
    For Each theControl As Control In container.Controls
        If TypeOf theControl Is Label Then    
            listOfLabels.Add(theControl)

            If theControl.Controls.Count > 0 Then
                GetAllLabelsIn(theControl)
            End If
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Now you can call it like this:

```
listOfLabels = new List(Of Control)

GetAllLabelsIn(myPanel)

For Each theControl As Control In listOfLabels
    If TypeOf theControl Is Label Then
        ' Change the text here
        TryCast(theControl, Label).Text = "whatever"
    End If
Next
```

Answer (score -1):

You can select only the `Label`s in the first place. This also returns labels inside containers inside containers etc...

```vb
' Inside a module
<Extension()> _
Public Function ChildControls(Of T As Control)(ByVal parent As Control) As List(Of T)
    Dim result As New ArrayList()
    For Each ctrl As Control In parent.Controls
        If TypeOf ctrl Is T Then result.Add(ctrl)
        result.AddRange(ChildControls(Of T)(ctrl))
    Next
    Return result.ToArray().Select(Of T)(Function(arg1) CType(arg1, T)).ToList()
End Function
```

Usage:

```
For Each myLabel as Label in myPanel.ChildControls(Of Label)
    myLabel.Text = "I'm a label!"
Next
```

Comment: Can you explain? I have used this method reliably for a while.

Comment: @JohnSaunders I just replaced the `ArrayList` with a `List(of Control)`, and tested both methods on a form with 1024 Labels inside 3 levels of containers. Both methods complete in 0 ms. Not worth updating my answer, because it was fine in the first place... unless you have some reason other than performance?

Comment: yeah, `ArrayList` is obsolete.